# How to change link color based on `theme.palette.type` in makeStyles?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to change link color if the palette is `dark` type:

```js
import {
  createMuiTheme,
  makeStyles,
  createStyles,
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";

export const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark",
  },
});

const useStyle = makeStyles((theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      "& a": {
        color: secondary_if_dark_mode,
      },
    },
  })
);
```

I know I can get the theme type by `theme.palette.type`, but I don't know how to specify the style based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
color : theme.palette.type === "dark" ? "secondary-color" : "other-color"
```

This should work.

Comment: I want to set default color if theme is not `dark`. Is it possible?

Comment: Ex: If it's inside the `theme.palette.colors` you can simply do like this.                                                        
`color : theme.palette.type === "dark" ? "secondary-color" : theme.palette.colors.yourDefaultColor`

Comment: https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/#providing-the-colors-directly

Comment: Default color is not defined by me. It is the color used in `<a>` usually.

Comment: `color : theme.palette.type === "dark" ?  "secondary-color" : null`